# Wifi card undetected after reboot on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04

After a reboot on ubuntu 18.04, my network adapter is unavaiable: I hqve the Message: **No Wifi-Adapter Found** in the settings.

I already tried this [solution](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392454), but it doesn't work. 
My machine is a **LENOVO Legion Y520**, and the result of `sudo lshw -C network` is the following:

```
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 99
   serial: e4:70:b8:85:ba:2e
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-38-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:136 memory:a4300000-a4301fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 10
   serial: 54:e1:ad:eb:a7:e7
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4204000-a4204fff memory:a4200000-a4203fff
*-network:0
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 3
   logical name: enp0s20f0u2
   serial: 9a:6b:7f:ea:db:b0
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.122 link=yes multicast=yes
*-network:1
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 4
   logical name: docker0
   serial: 02:42:b3:63:38:bb
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
*-network:2
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 5
   logical name: br-e0c0b5a11b0f
   serial: 02:42:10:5c:ab:39
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.19.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
*-network:3
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 6
   logical name: br-cd1d359cf403
   serial: 02:42:4d:59:ea:81
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.18.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

Comment: The solution is not applicable to your hardware. Your hardware is detected (first one in the list, driver/firmware correct, I guess). What hapens when you toggle the airplane mode on/off?

Comment: The airplane mode toggle doesn't do anything, when I press the key nothing happens. I can still use the bluetooth though, the airplane mode is not activated.

Comment: What did you upgrade, Uninstall or alter before your reboot

Comment: Nothing special, I just upgraded to 18.04.1 LTS from 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I had to re-activate the pilot using the commands:

`sudo rfkill list` and `sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop`